# PHP Form Post require once error

Tags: php

this form posts to a php file:

```
<form action="service/register.service.php" method="POST">
```

When the php file loads, it comes up with errors about this line:

```
3:   require_once 'service/user/user.service.php';
```

The errors are:

> Warning: require_once(service/user/user.service.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\TestApp\service\register.service.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'service/user/user.service.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\TestApp\service\register.service.php on line 3

These paths are pointing directly to the actual paths.

**Context**
The calling PHP file is `register.php`, I want this form to send the data to `service/register.service.php` where it can be processed, if there are any errors send the user back to `register.php` or send them to their new profile page.

I've checked the spelling and it is all correct.

The directorys are:

root/register.php
root/service/register.service.php
root/service/user/user.service.php

I'm not sure why it is doing this. I have copied the `require` statement out of another working file

Comment: could you explain the directory structure?

Comment: So do you have a `..../service/user` directory which has a `user.service.php` file in it?

Comment: i've added the directory structure

Comment: is it safe to assume that `root` is `C:\wamp\www\TestApp\\`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your entry point is `service/register.service.php` then the working directory will be `service`. Therefore any relative paths will be interpreted from that. So loose the `service/` prefix in the `require_once`:

```
require_once 'user/user.service.php';
```

Although you might want to consider having an initialisation script included that would set the working directory for all scripts to your root dir.

Comment: please expand on the working directory idea, sounds like something I really want

Comment: I would recommend you use relative paths for includes. I usually use `require_once __DIR__ . '/relative/path.php';`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this -

```
3:   require_once 'user/user.service.php';
```